# unable to download zip file from ADO via api

Tags: powershell, api, azure-devops

I am trying to download some files attached to the Work Item in ADO via API

for this I am using this powershell script

```
$organization= "<org name>"
$projectName = "<project name>"
$token = "<Azure token>"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "",$token)))

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$projectName/_apis/wit/attachments/{attachment ID}?fileName={file name}&download=true&api-version=5.0"

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/zip" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} | Out-File 'file name'
```

using this script I am able to download any text file but when I download any zip file, it doesn't open

It gives error saying

> The Compressed (zipped) Folder '{FilePath\FileName} is invalid.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Compressed (zipped) Folder '{FilePath\FileName} is invalid.'

I have tested your sample and reproduced the same issue.

[image]

To solve this issue, you need to change the `| Out-File 'file name'` to `-OutFile 'file name'`

Here is an example:

```
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/zip" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -OutFile 'file name'
```

Then the zip file can be opened successfully.

Comment: thanks for the solution, your solution worked perfectly